# Unable to update the linkLength of networkgraph highchart js

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using network graph of highchart but I can't update the link length between nodes when I click some point. [Here](https://codepen.io/w99910/pen/KKNNqVb) is the link to my code pen.

```
chart.update({
                    plotOptions:{
                      networkgraph:{
                        layoutAlgorithm:{
                          linkLength:50
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },true)
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Can you draw it as an example for me?

Comment: Here is my scenario. Since the network graph doesn't support zoom as far as I know, I tried to extract the network of the selected node and make it bigger like increasing the radius of the nodes but that process makes the link length invisible because the big nodes are covering the links between them. So I wanna extend the length so that the link between them can be visible. I'm sorry if I make it unclear but I hope you understand it. Let me know if I need to explain further.

Comment: Although I didn't find a way to update the linkLength, I found a solution to my scenario. I delete the option of initial linkLength and it will calculate automatically by the formula   "Math.pow(availableWidth * availableHeight / nodesLength, 0.4);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this config:

```
   chart.update({
    series: {
      nodes: nodes,
        link: {
          width: 50
      }
    }
  }, false);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eaqhx3t0/

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: It seems a little close to what I had in mind but I don't want big link. I just want long link between nodes. I wanna make longer distance between nodes.

Comment: @PatrickEdward Thanks for the replay! I played with it and it seems like a bug to me. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15134

Comment: Thank you for your time. How can I know if the bug would be fixed?

Comment: @PatrickEdward you can ask on Github, the core developers will prioritize this issue. Notice that the workaround also showed up, maybe it will be enough for your current needs for a while.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with link length. fixed it by making a state called "graphChange" and set it to true when it's sending data.when data comes back change it to false. This remakes the Highchart.

```js
const [graphChange, setGraphChange] = useState(false);
 return (<Fragment>
              <div className="col-md-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                        type="button"
                        className="btn btn-primary m-2"
                        value="Generate"
                        data-code=""
                        id="generate_graph_btn"
                        style={{ bottom: "9px", position: "absolute" }}
                        onClick={
                            relationState !== "" &&
                            (e => {
                                ShowNetworkGraph(relationState);
                                setGraphChange(true);
                            })
                        }
                    />
                </div>
              </div>
 
             <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">               
                        {networkData.length && graphChange === false && (
                        <HighchartsReact
                            highcharts={Highcharts}
                            options={chartOptions}
                            updateArgs={[true, true, true]}
                            allowChartUpdate={true}
                            ref={chartComponent}
                        />)}
                </div>
            </div>
</Fragment>);
```